# Passing a list from view into controller using AJAX in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been looking on the site for something similar, but all the questions are about passing a model to a controller. My question is: how can we pass a generic data (in my case, a list of strings). Here's what I have

In Javascript:

```js
var listOfParametersToPass = ["Peter","Paul"];
$.ajax({
        url: '/Home/InsertData',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { listOfParametersToPass: listOfParametersToPass },
        traditional:true,
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

Here's my controller

```c#
[HttpPost]
public void InsertData(string[] listOfParametersToPass)
{
     // Do data manipulation here
}
```

The issue is that listOfParametersToPass in the controller is null. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks so much..

Comment: try adding `traditional: true` and `dataType: "JSON"` to your ajax request

Comment: It turns out that this is a totally different problem than the one I posted above. My real problem is that VS runs an old version of my Javascript code. After restarting the machine, everything works. Thanks for your prompt responses though, SLC and @Jamie Cox. I think I should delete this question soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting single quotes in the line:

data: { 'listOfParametersToPass': listOfParametersToPass }